# ASP.NET MVC4 dynamic sitemap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am quite new in the world of asp.net and mvc4 so I've got a quite simple question. I have to write an application which has a hierarchie the user navigates through. There are differnt layers like settlement, section, machine,... For each layer I've created a view. If the user selects a settlement the controller of the section-view will display all sections which belong to the selected settlement. I want to display a path like

> Settlement 4 > Section X1 > Machine xxx

So what would be the best approach the do that? I want to keep it extensible and simple. But saving all elements of the hierarchie in a viewBag or sessions does not seems to be nice solution. Also using the database to do that seems a bit overkill. So what would you recommend to do?

Comment: Look for 'breadcrumbs' with MVC4, for example: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/creating-dynamic-breadcrumbs

Comment: Well the problem is that I need to do that with dynamic actions because I need to know which section was selected @Stephen